# BufferStrategy cleans Frame background

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, bufferstrategy

I have tried to make a simple GUI in Java Using `graphics2D` and `JFrame`.
I have added a background-color on JFrame typing `this.setBackground(new Color(54, 71, 99))` inside `initWindow()` method. It turned out that `backBuffer` was clearing that background and not repainting the line that causes this is in `render()` method, last line `backBuffer.show()`.

**How Do I make it *NOT* clear the main background?**

```
package asteroids;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends Canvas implements KeyListener {

    private boolean gameOver;
    private BufferStrategy backBuffer;  
    private Dimension dimension = new Dimension(Config.WINDOW_WH[0], Config.WINDOW_WH[1]);
    private List<Star> stars = new ArrayList<Star>();
    private HashMap<Integer,Boolean> keyDownMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

    public Main() {
        // Initialize Window
        initWindow();
        addKeyListener(this);

        this.setBackground(new Color(54, 71, 99));
        this.createBufferStrategy(2);               
        backBuffer = this.getBufferStrategy();

        // init variables
        gameOver = false;

        // Generating stars
        generateStars();

        // Init loop
        gameLoop();
    }

    public void initWindow(){
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Asteroids"); 
        setPreferredSize(dimension); 

        window.add(this);           
        window.pack();  
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true); 
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBackground(new Color(54, 71, 99));

        window.requestFocus();
    }

    public void update() {
        if(keyDownMap.containsKey(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)){
            gameOver = false;
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void render(){
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) backBuffer.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        for(Star s: stars) {
            g.fillOval(s.posx - (s.width/2), s.posy - (s.height/2), s.width, s.height);
        }
        g.dispose();
        backBuffer.show();
    }

    public void generateStars() {
        for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++) {
            int starX = new Random().nextInt(Config.WINDOW_WH[0]-10)+5;
            int starY = new Random().nextInt(Config.WINDOW_WH[1]-10)+5;
            stars.add(new Star(starX, starY));
        }
    }

    public void gameLoop(){
        while(!gameOver){
            update();
            render();

            try{ Thread.sleep(20);}catch(Exception e){};
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keyDownMap.put(e.getKeyCode(), true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keyDownMap.remove(e.getKeyCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 1):

> How Do I make it NOT clear the main background?

You can't.  Apart from `Canvas` been non-transparent (which can't be changed), `BufferStrategy` also has more then one page onto which it paints it's content (thus allowing to perform page flipping).  Combined, this would make it impossible to maintain the background of the parent container.

Instead, you should (in fact, you must) clear the `Graphics` context of the buffer you painting to do, every time `render` is called, otherwise you will be painting onto what ever was previously painted on to it.

One technique might be to generate a `BufferedImage` with the "static" content and simply paint that to the buffer first